# Draw a pie chart by percentage

Tags: imagemagick

How can I draw a pie chart by percentage with ImageMagick?

For example: if have a value like 45 given as percentage -- how do I draw a pie chart with just 45% with Ruby or bash command?

If I use ImageMagick's `draw` operator, how do the arc values need to be set? Or how can I calculate the acr values from an integer value?

E.G.:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:none -fill white -stroke black/
-draw "path 'M 30,40   A 1,1  0  0,0 70,20 ....  ??
```

I tried to read and understand the examples, but the arc calculation is a mystery for me.

Answer (score 8):

ImageMagick's `draw` operation implements the SVG 'paths' as defined in [this W3C document](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html).

To draw by giving simple 'degree' angle parameters is not supported. You need to calculate the endpoint coordinates of each path and sub-path which involves arcs by using trigonometric functions. (You have to use either absolute values, or relative values in relation to the current point, depending on the exact arc operator in use; see also example below.)

### General

In SVG (and for ImageMagick), a 'path' represents the outline of an object. Drawing a compound path is also supported: a compound path is a path with subpaths, where each subpath consists of a single `moveto` followed by one or more `line` or `curve` operations.

The outlines of objects may be defined by the following operations:

- **`moveto :`** *set a new current point.*
  Use **`M`** for absolute and **`m`** for relative movements.
- **`lineto :`** *draw a straight line.*
  Use **`L`** for absolute and **`l`** for relative movements.
- **`curveto :`** *draw a Bezier curve.*
  Use **`C`**, **`c`**, **`S`** and **`s`** to draw [*cubic Bezier curves*](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands). (We do not need these for pie charts).
  Use **`Q`**, **`q`**, **`T`** and **`t`** to draw [*quadratic Bezier curves](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataQuadraticBezierCommands). (We do not need these for pie charts).
- **`arc :`** *draw an elliptical or circular arc.*
  Use **`A`** and **`a`** to draw [*elliptic arcs*](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands). We need these for pie charts for the special case where *ellipse == circle*.
- **`closepath :`** *close the current shape by drawing a line to the last moveto.*
  Use **`Z`** or **`z`**; both have identical effects: they end the current subpath and cause an automatic straight line to be drawn from the current point to the initial point of the current subpath.

  - If a "closepath" is followed immediately by a "moveto", then the "moveto" identifies the starting point of the next subpath.
  - If a "closepath" is followed immediately by any other command, then the next subpath starts at the same initial point as the current subpath.

### Single piechart wedge example

This means, you can draw a single red pie chart wedge with black borders inside a 280x280 canvas using a yellow background with this command:

```
convert         \
  -size 280x280 xc:yellow \
  -stroke black \
  -fill blue    \
  -draw "path 'M 120,140  L 120,40  A 100,100 0 0,1 137.36,41.52  Z'" \
   red-pie-wedge.jpg
```

**Result:**
[image: red piechart wedge]

1. The origin for the following coordinate system is the upper left corner.
2. The path's starting point (`M`) is at pixel coordinates *(120/140)*.
3. The first line (`L`) draws vertically upward from there to coordinate *(120/40)*.
4. From coordinate *(120/40)* an circular arc (`A`) of radius *100* goes to coordinate *(137.36/41.52)*.
   I'll leave it to the reader to work out the trigonometric calculation that leads to coord *(137.36/41.52)* as the arc's end point. Hints:

   - The wedge's angle is 10°, and *100*sin(10°)=17.36* because the *radius* in this example is *100*, hence *120+17.36=137.36* ;
   - *cos(10°)=0.9848* and *100*(1-cos(10°))=1.52*, hence *40+1.52=41.52* .
5. From the arc's end point, the path is closed (`Z`) with a straight line back to the path's starting point.

### Complete pie chart example

**You always need to do some trigonometrical math to calculate the endpoints of any circular arcs** which are needed to draw all the pie wedges.

Here is the example of a complete pie chart, which includes the above blue pie wedge:

```
convert                  \
 -size 280x280 xc:yellow \
 -stroke black           \
 -fill blue   -draw "path 'M 120,140  L 120.00,40.00  A 100,100  0 0,1  137.36,41.52  Z'" \
 -fill silver -draw "path 'M 120,140  L 137.36,41.52  A 100,100  0 0,1  154.20,46.00  Z'" \
 -fill red    -draw "path 'M 136,130  L 170.20,36.00  A 100,100  0 0,1  236.00,130.00 Z'" \
 -fill green  -draw "path 'M 120,140  L 220.00,140.00 A 100,100  0 1,1  120.00,40.00  Z'" \
 -fill black  -stroke none  -pointsize 10 \
 -draw "text 119,37 '10' text 142,41 '10' text 182,36 '70' text 226,156 '270'" \
  piechart.jpg
```

**Result:**
[image: complete piechart]

Comment: So this is odd, i tried to repoduce the simple Pie Example using Ruby, but no way, the hinted Sinus/Cosinus Values are not possible to recreate, Ruby calcs always something different, see:

Comment: ang = 270


sinus =  100 * Math.sin(10) +120
cosinus =  100 * (1-Math.cos(10)) + 40

puts sinus
puts cosinus

res ='convert         \
  -size 280x280 xc:none \
  -stroke black \
  -fill blue    \
  -draw "path \'M 120,140  L 120,40  A 100,100 0 0,1 '+sinus.to_s+','+cosinus.to_s+'  Z\'" \
   red-pie-wedge.png'
   

exec res

Comment: This should help you: https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/unit-circle.html